# TLS 1.2 upgrade and War file update

Tags: java, tomcat, war, tls1.2

One simple question .

Since i am not a dev person so not so sure . 
We are using an application which uses java , tomcat  and My SQL Database with TLS 1.1 
Since TLS 1.1 is reaching EOL , we are looking to update rest of the components to support TLS 1.2

If i do any changes with java and tomcat and update them to latest version , will there be any update required in the war file deployed for application or i can use same war file ? I guess we would need to change but want to take experts opinion .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies used in your project might use a different version when you upgrade.
It really depends on what is used inside the project. Easiest way to check is to try it on a new server and see if it works.
Most likely if you upgrade Java there will be some things that need to be updated but those changes are usually minor (easy to implement).

Comment: Thank you . I was checking other threads and realized if we have windows 2008 and IIS 7.5, we dont really need to change the java and tomcat version and only by changing the registry setting , TLS 1.2 can be updated and should be fine . Any views on this ? By the way we were in planning to upgrade to windows 2012 as well .

Comment: On one of the servers i maintain which is running an application for government use, We are using Java 8 and ubuntu18.03. precisely because we didn't want to update dependencies and deal with the hassle of testing everything as there are thousands of options in the application. Using older Java or other components is fine as long as you dont want or need to modify the application, and even if you do you can always add code that relies on the older version of Java.